# AWS javascript SDK Kinesis getShardIterator Error: UnexpectedParameter: Unexpected key 'Timestamp' found in params

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-kinesis

I am using the aws-sdk(version 2.1.8) to get records out from Kinesis. This is within a node Lambda function. Trying to use ShardIteratorType: AT_TIMESTAMP. I supply a Timestamp in the params object

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis({ region: 'us-east-1' });
var params = {
    ShardId: shard.ShardId, /* required */
    ShardIteratorType: 'AT_TIMESTAMP', /* required */
    StreamName: process.env.STREAM_NAME, /* required */
    Timestamp: new Date(2017, 11, 08, 14, 32, 51)
};

kinesis.getShardIterator(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
        return defer.reject(err);
    }
    defer.resolve(data);
});
```

But I get this error: *Unexpected key 'Timestamp' found in params*.  Checked google, SO, and aws forums, to no avail. I am following the documentation from AWS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Kinesis.html#getShardIterator-property

Here are the logs from the Lambda function where I use getShardIterator

```
2017-11-08T15:53:13.551Z    ec3ef291-c49c-11e7-ad35-473206669891    SHARD 
ITERATOR TYPE:  AT_TIMESTAMP
2017-11-08T15:53:13.551Z    ec3ef291-c49c-11e7-ad35-473206669891    
TIMESTAMP:  2017-12-08T14:32:51.000Z
```

ShardIteratorTypes LATEST and TRIM_HORIZON work fine. It is only when I try to use AT_TIMESTAMP that the issue occurs.

Comment: Can you include the code that is calling the SDK, passing the params variable?

Comment: added the aws kinesis library init & call to getShardIterator

Comment: Using a recent aws-sdk version (2.145.0), I don't have any problems passing the Timestamp parameter. It does fail with InvalidParameterType when passing the timestamp in the format you've specified but supplying the following seems to be acceptable: Timestamp: new Date(2017, 11, 08, 14, 32, 51).

Comment: Interesting. I will test it now.

Comment: @jarmod I tested using your suggested value for Timestamp - still get the same error. I have updated my post with the logs output. It shows that I have valid values for ShardIteratorType and Timestamp. This is all happening inside a Lambda function, if that means anything.

Comment: Strange. This works fine for me in Lambda (using Node.js 6.10 runtime and default JavaScript SDK supplied by Lambda). Is there any chance that you are mistakenly passing that params object into a different SDK call (one that doesn't accept a Timestamp) or you are mis-reading the CloudWatch Logs from your Lambda function? Can you add more console.log() statements to debug it in more detail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158532/discussion-between-jarmod-and-blighty).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what was going on. The aws-sdk is taking the Timestamp value and multiplying it by 1000. This is insane - nowhere is this mentioned in the docs, where it simply states

> The timestamp of the data record from which to start reading. Used with shard iterator type AT_TIMESTAMP. A timestamp is the Unix epoch date with precision in milliseconds

Therefore, using this

> Timestamp: 1510673368611

will fail, even though it is a valid timestamp in milliseconds. You have to divide by 1000

> Timestamp: 1510673368.611

This was pretty infuriating to discover. Just validate the value I send, don't alter it and then validate the result. Or, you know, MENTION THAT THIS HAPPENS IN THE DOCS.